# Retrieving Data from mySQL and display in PopUp

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql

I am retrieving data from mySQL using PHP and able to show it, like the Job Titles in List Items. And would like to show the Job Skills and Description in a PopUp when it is clicked. Each Job Title will have unique Skills and Description. Please, help me...

Sample Code :

```
<?php

//including the database connection file
include_once("includes/db.php");


// Get all the data from the table
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM job_posting ORDER BY id DESC") or die(mysql_error());  

echo "<ul>";
// keeps getting the next row until there are no more to get
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    // Print out the contents of each row into a table
    echo "<li> <a href='post_resume.php?id=".base64_encode($row['id'])."'>" . $row['title'] . "</a></li>";
}
echo "<ul>";

?>
```

Comment: you can do an alert or use Jquery-UI dialog http://jqueryui.com/dialog/

Comment: Your question should state the problem you are facing so that someone can help, at-least post some code which is not working. You will not get the solution until your question is clear.

Comment: I have updated the code plz. check

Comment: I don't understand how vote-downs are constructive. He is a new user and could take time adapting to this platform.

Answer (score 0):

With reference to : http://jqueryui.com/dialog/

Put a div inside your li .

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
          <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
          <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>

      <script>
      $(function() {
        $( ".dialog" ).dialog({ autoOpen: false });
      });
      </script>
<body>



 <ul>   
  <li>   
    <div class="dialog" title="SOME TEXT">
      <p>

                     JOB SKILLS AND DESCRIPTION

       </p>
    </div>    </li>  </ul>  </body>
```

Comment: Sorry for the bad formatting - the Stackoverflow markup was eating up tags. :(

Comment: PopUp is automatically generating for each Title... I have updated the code like this : <?php
// Get all the data from the table
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM job_posting ORDER BY id DESC") or die(mysql_error());  

echo "<ul>";
// keeps getting the next row until there are no more to get
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
 // Print out the contents of each row into a table
 echo "<li><div class='dialog' title=''> <a href=''>" . $row['title'] . "</a></div></li>";
}
echo "<ul>";
?>

Comment: Update the above code I sent with php dynamic code. What do you mean by popUp is automatiaclly generated?

Comment: With ur give code I have updated, but it's coming automatically. I do not want want the PopUp to be generated automatically untill it is clicked on the Link. And how can I show the Skills and Description data in that PopUp... Thanks in advance...